# How can I update many rows so the date column in each row has a unique date?

Tags: mysql, random, unique

I have a database table with many rows which are already populated with data.  This data was generated using *generatedata.com*'s online data generation form.

Most if it is fine, but the problem is that many of the generated date fields are duplicates, and for my purposes I'd need them to be unique, and ideally within a reasonable/specified range.

For example, say I want to populate the `date` column for every row with a random but unique date between 2010-01-01 and today.  Is there a MySQL query or set of queries I can use to do this quickly?

Technically something like this would work fine for the random part:

```
UPDATE table 
SET date = CONCAT( FLOOR(2010 + (RAND() * (2013-2010)) ),
        '-',
        FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * (12-1))),'-',FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * (28-1))))
```

It doesn't have to account for every possible date.  They just have to be valid dates, so the above line gives me random dates within a range, but what could I add to make sure they are all unique?

Comment: if you've got a simple int ID string, then `update table set datefield=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() + id)` would do it. or perhaps `set datefield=now() + INTERVAL id SEC`.

Comment: I'm assuming that 'many rows' is less than 365*3 - how important is randomness even? you could just start with the start date and add total_records/ 365*3 days x the row you are on... that would spread them all out evenly and uniquely

Comment: Marc B, wouldn't that only offset the time by seconds?  It looks like the actual dates (days) could still be the same.

Comment: If you do not care about the data, why not just loop through your preferred date range and insert them for each row?

Comment: Randy, it's not really THAT important.  It's more important that they are unique.  Could you give me your solution idea in the form of a query I can use?

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee, I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: Instead of using the rand function, you could just begin with 1-jan-2010 for your first row, 2-jan-2010 for your second row, etc. That way you are guaranteed to insert all the dates you like, without repetition, and you'll know exactly where they are.

Comment: Here is a link to a non-SO post on how to generate rownums: http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/09/13/rownum-simulation-with-mysql/. It uses a user-defined variable and a product join of one row to increment.  In your case, start the sequence with a date and increment by one day.  If I knew MySQL better, I'd answer directly.

Comment: Random is not unique for calendar dates. In fact, among a group of 23 people, it's more than 50% likely that two share the same birthday.

Answer (score 0):

**Use mysqldump and export the whole table into a text file WHICH IS "|" SEPARATED.**

Looks like below,

table.dat

```
1|aa@aa.com|<<date_column>>
2|aa@aa.com|<<date_column>>
3|bb@b.com|<<date_column>>
```

---

```
 1. Use AWK, SED, SHELL, PERL or RUBY (I love ruby) and replace the last
   column with a loop on the time given out by the chosen scripting
   language. Implement your own logic here. 

 2. Make sure your final dat file doesn't have any duplicate date.
```

**Load the final.dat into the table!**

Comment: Well, for one, I don't know any of those languages.  I work mostly with PHP.  Also, this is a bit more work than it's really worth. I was mostly hoping for a quick query solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ID column with a unique integer for each row in your table?  If so, do this:

```
  UPDATE `table` 
     SET `date` = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL `id` DAY
```

This will give you a different date on each row, counting backward from today.  That should meet your need.  If for some reason you need them to count forward from a fixed date, try this instead.

```
  UPDATE `table` 
     SET `date` = '2010-01-01' + INTERVAL `id` DAY
```

**Edit**

If your id numbers don't start at zero or one, try this, as @Randy suggested:

```
UPDATE `table` 
   SET `date` = '2010-01-01' +
         INTERVAL (`id` - (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM `table`) ) DAY
```

Comment: Hmmmm, this is actually not a bad idea.  However, the numbers in the ID column are already well into the thousands, so wouldn't it be counting thousands of days from the specified date?

Comment: you could always 'normalize' thos big numbers back to 1 by subtracting the lowest one from everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a similar query statement for Chapter 9 Head First SQL. Here is what I did:

str_to_date( concat( floor( 1 + rand() * (12-1)), '-', floor(1 + rand() * (28 -1)), '-', **(1999 + FLOOR(RAND() * (2013-1999 +1)))), '%m-%d-%Y')**